# Why does miniblog fail to save files when running as virtual application on azure app service

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-web-app-service

I can create a new blog post and see the content via the website, however if I restart the website the post is gone.

- I have confirmed that there are no xml files getting created via kudu and ftp. There is no error thrown it seems though.
- When running locally under IIS express the xml file is created. I can create xml files locally and publish them.

(I have the blog hosted in virtual app under /blog)

https://github.com/madskristensen/MiniBlog/issues/233

I am double-posting on issues and here as it's so annoying and perhaps someone has been through it before.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I had turned on local cache (and not thought of this impact):
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-local-cache/

Comment: Would be nice to be able to have both, but then I guess I need a separate site for the blog rather than a virtual application. Anyway nothing to do with miniblog, azure specific.